# How to create pdf file of the webview content in titanium

Tags: pdf, webview, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am new to Titanium. I have a `webview`. The content of the `webview` can be a `pdf` file, or a `url`. I want to save the `webview` content as a `pdf` file.  I have created webview using the below code:

```
    var webViews = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    left : 0,
    top : 0,
    right : 0,
    bottom : 0, 

    url : 'http://www.appcelerator.com'
    });
```

Please anyone help me out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant directly convert the webview data in pdf but you have to first parse html and then use the js pdf to create the pdf.Here is the code with example

https://github.com/Mindelusions/TiJSPDF

Thanks