# Converting HTML String into pdf

Tags: javascript, html, titanium

I am converting an `HTML` string into a `pdf` document using following code.

It converts the `HTML` to `pdf` well enough, but when I add the an `img` tag to the `HTML` it does not render the image in the `pdf`.

Here is the code I am using.

```
 var htmlString="<H1>Hello This is Text</H1> <img src='zid.png'>";

 function generatePDF(htmlString) {
    if(htmlString!=null) {
       alert("Html String: "+htmlString);
        Ti.App.fireEvent("generatePDFfromString",{
                           "htmlString":htmlString,
                           "fileName":'MyFileName.pdf'
                         });
    }
 };

 function gotPDF(filePath){
    alert("Html String: "+filePath);
    Ti.App.fireEvent("sendEmail",{
                       "fileURL":filePath,"subject":'My File Subject',
                       "messageBody":"",
                       "toReceipients":[""]
                     });
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create pdf file of the webview content in titanium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915752/how-to-create-pdf-file-of-the-webview-content-in-titanium)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Before**

```
 var htmlString="<H1>Hello This is Text</H1> <img src='zid.png'>";
```

**After**

```
 var htmlString="<H1>Hello This is Text</H1> <img src='zid.png'/>";
```